# strcmp with string ending with newline

Tags: c, string, newline, strcmp

I'm trying to write a C list filtering function that receives a country string, traverses the list and deletes all nodes with `node->country == country`. The problem is that `node->country` strings end with `'\n'` (because it's being read from a csv file) and therefore `strcmp(node->country, country)` never equals zero.

How would I solve this? I first thought about appending `'\n'` to country but that would probably raise more memory problems. Also thought about `strstr` but I don't really know how to work with that.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why do *node->country strings* end with a newline?  Can't you remove that before you store them in the list?

Comment: replace the newlines with NULL terminators.

Comment: Use `std::getline` and store both as `std::string`.

Comment: filter non alpha-numeric characters

Comment: @ChristianGibbons How would I do that?

Comment: @wally: It looks like OP is writing C.

Comment: @returnNULL Search through the string and find the `'\n'` character and replace it with `'\0'`

Comment: @returnNULL Stephan Lechner's answer does this.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Wasteful. If `node->country` begins with `'a'` but `country` begins with `'b'` - why bother?

Comment: @einpoklum We're talking about your alternative #3.

Comment: It is best to remove the newline retained by `fgets` *at the point of entry*. It might be unwise to input directly to the `struct` member.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `strcmp`, let's assume some C-style code:

```
node->country[strcspn(node->country, "\n")] = '\0';
```

This will alter your `node->country` value and terminate your string right before a new line (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Suggested alternatives:

1. Precompute

   ```
   size_t len_of_country = strlen(country)
   ```

   and use

   ```
   (strncmp(country, node->country, len_of_country) == 0 &&
    (node->country[len_of_country] == '\n' || 
    node->country[len_of_country] == '\0'))
   ```

   as the match criterion.
2. Same as (1.), but if the latter case, also set `node->country[len_of_country]` to 0 for later use.
3. Make your CSV parser chomp the trailing newline when reading the country string from the file, and just use `strcmp()`.

Comment: For option 3, how do I "chomp" the newline, using 1. ?

Comment: @returnNULL: Well, that depends on what you use to read you CSV file, which is a detail I don't have. If you're not using any library, consider doing so. There are at least [two](https://github.com/fiksu/rcsv/network) different [ones](https://github.com/robertpostill/libcsv/network) on GitHub and a (more classic?) [libcsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/), but I haven't tried them myself.

Comment: I tried option 1 with node->country = "France\n" and country = "France" and it returns 0, isn't it supposed to return 1? 
And the parser simply uses a strtok

Comment: @returnNULL: Oh, sorry, I mis-copy-pasted. I meant that after the  `strncmp()` passes you also check the last character. See edit.